# Ошибка class not found

Tags: java, jar

При компиляции кода в IntelliJ IDEA всё работает отлично, но как только вывожу `.jar` и пытаюсь запустить его, пишет ошибку:

[image: Так это выглядит в cmd]

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class General {

    public static int KM = 0;

    public static void main (String[] agrs){
        System.out.println("Добро пожаловать, Екатерина. \nЧто вас интересует? \n1 - Посмотреть данные \n2 - Внести данные");

        Scanner scan1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner scan4 = new Scanner(System.in);
        int select1 = scan1.nextInt();

        if (select1 == 1) {
            ViewSelect();
        } else if (select1 == 2) {
            ChangSelect();
        }

        if (select1 != 1 || select1 != 2) {
            while (select1 != 1 || select1 != 2){
                System.out.println("Вы ввели неверное число, попробуйте снова");
                select1 = scan4.nextInt();
                if (select1 == 1) {
                    ViewSelect();
                    break;
                }
                if (select1 == 2) {
                    ChangSelect();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

    }

    public static void ViewSelect() {
        System.out.println("Ваш суммарный метраж - " + KM + " метров");
        WelcomeAgain();
    }

    public static void ChangSelect() {
        System.out.println("Какое количество метров сегодня вы прошли?");
        Scanner scan3 = new Scanner(System.in);
        int select3 = scan3.nextInt();
        KM = KM + select3;
        System.out.println("Данные успешно внесены, ваш суммарны метраж - " + KM + " метров");
        WelcomeAgain();
    }

    public static void WelcomeAgain() {
        System.out.println("Желаете что-то ещё, Екатерина?.\n1 - Посмотреть данные \n2 - Внести данные");
        Scanner scan2 = new Scanner(System.in);
        int select2 = scan2.nextInt();
        if (select2 == 1) {
            ViewSelect();
        } else if (select2 == 2) {
            ChangSelect();
        }
        if (select2 != 1 || select2 != 2) {
            while (select2 != 1 || select2 != 2){
                System.out.println("Вы ввели неверное число, попробуйте снова");
                select2 = scan2.nextInt();
                if (select2 == 1) {
                    ViewSelect();
                    break;
                }
                if (select2 == 2) {
                    ChangSelect();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Вот что прописано в `MANIFEST`:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: General
```

Comment: Ну он же вам написал, что не может найти `Main` класс пакета. Исполняемый по умолчанию класс не найден.

Comment: Как вы собираете проект в jar?

Comment: @Rootware Из текста указанного в ошибке я это понял, но почему он не может его найти? в манифесте указан при компиляции main class, даже если архиватором открыть .jar, то там тоже класс лежит.
И ещё, заметил странность, которая указывает на то, что проблема не в коде, а в чём-то другом, потому что даже если написать самый элементарный Hello Word чтобы выводился в консоль, то он ту же самую проблему пишет, хотя во фреймворке работает и даже через консоль фреймворка если запускаю этот .jar - работает, а через cmd нет

Comment: @МаксимБродский [По этой статье, штатными средствами фреймворка](https://javarush.ru/groups/posts/1352-kak-sozdatjh-ispolnjaemihy-jar-v-intellij-idea--how-to-create-jar-in-idea)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В файле `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` пропишите строку:

```
Main-Class: com.example.Main
```

Более подробно про создание точки входа в программу можно почитать [здесь](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html).

То есть главный класс который указан должен содержать главный метод

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

По вашей ошибке видно что программа не может найти класс, который указан в манифесте и поэтому возникает [`ClassNotFoundException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassNotFoundException.html).

Comment: Не помогло, точка входа разумеется у меня есть (добавил в вопрос свой код полностью и данные MANIFEST.

Comment: Какую команду вы используете для запуска?

Comment: Никакую, просто двойной ЛКМ по Test1.jar

Comment: А консоль программы запускается?

Comment: Появляется на 1 секунду, выкидывает ошибку (скриншот в вопросе есть) и закрывается

Comment: Перетащите файл Test1.jar в папку с проектом. Создайте ярлык для Test1.jar, ПКМ свойства, затем в свойстве `Объект:` перед путем к файлу пропишите `java -jar `.

Comment: Пишет: Имя конечного файла "java" задан неправильно. Проверьте правильность указанного пути и имени файла. Вот так выглядит путь: java -jar C:\Users\User\IdeaProjects\Test1\out\artifacts\Test1_jar\Test1.jar

Comment: Ну если она не находит путь к файлу `java.exe`, то надо его прописать вручную.

Comment: Нет, при попытке сохранить ярлык с заданным параметрами он пишет эту ошибку и не даёт сохранить

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82322/discussion-between-roman-c-and-andrew).

Comment: Нашёл решение проблемы
Наверно нагадил в системе кучей пакетов Javа. 
Я удалил все Java программы, компиляторы и всё что с этим связанно, удалил все переменные Path, заново поставил пакет JDK, создал системную переменную Path и указал путь до папки bin в пакете JDK (без указания java.exe) и ОС начала запускать .jar файлы как и должно быть, спасибо за уделённое время моей проблеме))

Answer (score 1):

Создайте новый проект. Скопируйте Ваш код в него. Проделайте все этапы заново.

META-INF/MANIFEST.MF должен быть такой:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: General
```

Убедитесь что Вы запускаете jar файл так (*только ж адресс к файлу свой укажите*):

java -jar D:\Test1.jar

При указанных параметрах у меня все запускается.

P.S. IntelliJ IDEA - не фреймворк, а  интегрированная среда разработки. На будущее рекомендую изучить одну из систем сборки (например, Maven).

Comment: Мне кажется я ещё очень слабо знаю основы, чтобы начинать изучать Maven, да и в принципе толком не знаю что такое Maven  и для чего он. 

Что, если не секрет, является фреймворком?(я даже не знал про это)

Строку "java -jar D:\Test1.jar" где необходимо прописать?

Comment: Откуда Вы пробуете запустить свой Test1.jar и как?

Comment: Захожу в директорию, где хранится Test1.jar и двойной клик ЛКМ по нему.

Comment: И что Вы хотите в результате получить? На данном этапе у Вас консольное приложение и вы можете его запустить только через командную строку Windows либо же через свою среду разработки. Если я правлильно понял, то Вы хотите чтоб у Вашей программы был визуальный интерфейс. Для этого Вам стоит изучить хотя бы основы библиотеки Swing. Поищите в интернете, очень много уроков есть по этой теме.

Comment: Я хочу в итоге чтобы .jar файл можно было запускать двойным щелчком ЛКМ по нему.
Я знаю что это консольное приложение и мне этого на данном этапе разработки достаточно, потому что я пока пытаюсь прописать основную логику работы программы, после чего уже собираюсь добавить интерфейс через Swing (хотел JavaFX использовать, но узнал что он скоро не будет поддерживаться в Java).
О существовании пакетов Swing, AWT, JavaFX мне известно и даже пару раз работал с ними, изучая книгу.
Просто до этого когда я писал код, то он запускался после щелчка ЛКМ по ярлыку .jar файла, странно.